# Transition from root to non-root user

Tags: ssh, security, root

I have an Ubuntu droplet set up with DigitalOcean and have it pretty much running as expected and am ready to take it live.  However, in following the extensive DigitalOcean setup instructions, one thing I did skip was the non-root user setup.  I don't remember why I did that, but I did.  Right now I'm accessing the droplet via SSH but I don't even have a root password (yikes, maybe?).  I also have a firewall set up with NGINX, etc. and all of the standard recommendations based on DigitalOcean's setup articles.

I'm reading through this list of VPS security precautions and the first item is to remove root access.

https://www.eurovps.com/blog/20-ways-to-secure-linux-vps/

I'm still very much new to Ubuntu and I'm wondering how I should go about transitioning from the root setup to a non-root one.  I've made a decent number of changes to the default configuration and don't want to have to start from scratch.

Part of the reason I'm asking this question is that I may eventually want to store some fairly sensitive private keys on a droplet.  I've read that VPS might be inherently insecure so also I'm trying to figure out if it's possible for me to get a sufficient level of security on a droplet or if I should give up on that altogether.  I like DigitalOcean but I guess I would need to look elsewhere for a non-VPS solution.

Comment: Read `man adduser`. After adding the user, add the user to the `sudo` group.  Set up your `ssh` access, and test, Test, TEST! to be sure it works (`sudo id`), before disabling `root`.

Comment: I understand how to add a user and how to set up SSH access.  My question is about how to make sure everything works after doing so.  I guess the obvious answer is just what you said - to test everything out before disabling root.

Comment: The reason I thought to ask this is that all of my code is in the root folder.  Dumb question, I'm sure, but would I need to change that at any point?

Comment: Yes. Use `mv` to move files from `~root` to `~user` (or take this as an opportunity to reorganize your code storage), then, logged in as `user`, do `sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) *`. Then, rebuild your software.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I realize this is hard to answer without specific knowledge of my setup, but is it likely I'd need to change any config files to make sure they refer to the right user?  I've been tinkering with the server for a couple months while writing back-end code and largely making ad-hoc changes when I've run into issues.  Just wondering if it's common for config files (e.g., nginx, pm2, mongoDB, etc.) to require references to specific users.